# Parse .iso files in Python

Tags: python, parsing, iso

I want to parse .iso file in python. I want to get information and data from .iso

for example there is a iso file, its name xyz.iso
but in fact it is a ubuntu image and it has file like Readme.txt, .deb pacges etc.
How can i do for this?

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried [Hachoir](https://pypi.org/project/hachoir/)? It allows you to view or edit binary streams, and it supports ISO as shown on their [documentation](https://hachoir.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parser.html#file-system). It would allow you to browse the files and folders inside the ISO file.

Comment: it can work thanks. but can you give example code? I don't know how can i use it?

Comment: the links are broken

Answer (score 1):

You can use for listing and extracting, I tested the first.

https://github.com/barneygale/iso9660/blob/master/iso9660.py

```
import iso9660
cd = iso9660.ISO9660("/Users/murat/Downloads/VisualStudio6Enterprise.ISO")
for path in cd.tree():
    print path
```